# 'x' is not a function when passing parameters in Kotlin Javascript

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

I keep getting this error: *TypeError: Scraper.dumpTitle is not a function*

And I can't figure out why...

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kotlin JS Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="out/production/lib/kotlin.js"></script>
<script src="out/production/Scraper.js"></script>
    <!--<script>-->
        <!--function loaded() {-->
        <!--}-->
    <!--</script>-->

    <script>
        $(function() {
            Scraper.dumpTitle(document)
        })

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

## Main.js

```
import kotlin.browser.document

/**
 *  *
 *  * -
 */
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello")
}

fun dumpTitle(doc: dynamic) {
    println(doc.title)
}
fun dumpTitle1() {
    println(document.title)
}
```

## generated js

```
if (typeof kotlin === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error("Error loading module 'Scraper'. Its dependency 'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 'Scraper'.");
}
var Scraper = function (_, Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var println = Kotlin.kotlin.io.println_s8jyv4$;
  function main(args) {
    println('Hello');
  }
  function dumpTitle(doc) {
    println(doc.title);
  }
  function dumpTitle1() {
    println(document.title);
  }
  _.main_kand9s$ = main;
  _.dumpTitle_za3rmp$ = dumpTitle;
  _.dumpTitle1 = dumpTitle1;
  Kotlin.defineModule('Scraper', _);
  main([]);
  return _;
}(typeof Scraper === 'undefined' ? {} : Scraper, kotlin);
```

### notes

1. calling `dumpTitle1()` works fine.. so the problem I have is only with passing parameters
2. no need to point out that I can access the `document` variable in Kotlin without needing to pass it, I know... but I wanted to pass another `document` object to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're calling a Kotlin function from JavaScript, you need to use the `@JsName` annotation to give it a stable name. See [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html#jsname-annotation) for documentation.

```
@JsName("dumpTitle")
fun dumpTitle(doc: dynamic) {
    println(doc.title)
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that, I skimmed over that part of the documentation because I thought it was for overloaded functions only. Now I know better

Comment: Oh, BTW. .should it be dynamic or type Document?